# Two identical words are different

Tags: java

I am using sqlite to do a login, however to compare the login and database words I used the following code:

```
public static boolean result(String nome, String pass) {
Connection c = null;
Statement stmt = null;
boolean bo = false;
try {
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    c = DriverManager
            .getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:/Users/M4UR0/Desktop/Pastas/Programação/Java/Albamoura/data.db");
    c.setAutoCommit(false);

    stmt = c.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM COMPANY where NAME = '" + nome + "';"); //

    String password = rs.getString("PASSWORD");
    if (rs.next() || !pass.equalsIgnoreCase(password)) {
        bo = false;
        System.out.println("deu1 " + password + " - " + pass);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Entrou!");
        bo = true;
    }

    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
    c.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
    System.exit(0);
    bo = false;
}
System.out.println("Operation done successfully");
return bo;
```

}

And console say:

> Conecção estabelecida!
>
> deu1 word - word
>
> Operation done successfully
>
> false

2 identical words appear as different, did not I notice something? Help pls

Comment: What is a "stromg"?

Comment: its words sorry.

Comment: I've also noticed the `stmt.executeQuery(...)` line is prone to SQL injection, you may want to use prepared statements instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your boolean logic is off here

```
(rs.next() || !pass.equalsIgnoreCase(password))
```

that should be

```
(rs.next() && !pass.equalsIgnoreCase(password))
```

with an `||` it doesn't evaluate the next condition (short-circuits) *when* you have a row. Note that your `else` is also specious - because if there is no row then you appear to also set it to success.